# How can I set a face/style in emacs for a quotation in org mode?

Tags: org-mode, faces

Org mode supports quotations with the following syntax

```
#+begin_quote
To boldly go where no man has gone before
#+end_quote
```

I would like to make this region italic by default. Is there a variable for this?

Comment: Org mode doesn't seem to provide a face for quotes (try running `C-u C-x =` inside a quoted string), so it's not possible **easily**.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variable `org-fontify-quote-and-verse-blocks` controls whether special faces called `org-quote` and `org-verse` are assigned to quote and verse blocks. It is nil by default, meaning that no special faces are assigned.

You can customize this variable or put something like `(setq org-fontify-quote-and-verse-blocks t)` into your config to change its value. You need to run `font-lock-update` for changes to take effect (which for example happens when you restart Org mode).

You can change the default `org-quote` face like you would change any other face (see the [Emacs Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Face-Customization.html)), for example by using `M-x customize-face RET org-quote RET`.